# Optimize python if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is a more pythonic way to write this statement?

```
if soup.find(title="Email"):
    profile['email'] = soup.find(title="Email").a.string
```

What I want to avoid is the repetition of `soup.find(title="Email")`

Comment: Then extract it to a variable; this is not a Python issue, it's the same for pretty much every language going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if this is more pythonic. I do this with most languages I use.
On the top of my head, something like this should avoid the repetition.

```
soupByEmail = soup.find(title="Email")
if soupByEmail:
    profile['email'] = soupByEmail.a.string
```

Comment: You used two ifs and even if you didn't it wouldn't be valid. You're thinking of Ruby.

Comment: @AlexHall Ah yes, this only works if there is an else condition as well. 
`profile['email'] = soupByEmail.a.string if soupByEmail else " "`
Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of pythonic it's more about coding style. And as an elegant alternative you use [EAFP principle](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) (Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission) and wrap your snippet with a `try-except` expression:

```
try:
    profile['email'] = soup.find(title="Email").a.string
except Exception as exp:
    # do what you want with exp
```

Another advantage of this approach is that you can log the issues in your exception block, for later use, or print then in stdout.

Comment: The original code specifically distinguished between `find` returning a valid object with the appropriate `a` attribute and (presumably) `None`. You can do the same here by catching `AttributeError`, not `Exception`.

Comment: @chepner Maybe, but since there would be a lot of exception in that line, I can't rely on what I'm not sure about 100%, also OP doesn't explained the code completely.

Comment: "Optimizing" generally means the OP is asking for code that does the same thing as their code, and this does not meet that requirement.